# ODEintWarning: Illegal input detected (internal error)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ode

I want to solve a ODEs like this in python:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsroQ.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cde(y,t,r1,r2,l1,l2,m,c):
    #define the vecter of dependent variables
    i1,i2,uc = y
    #define the system of first order equations
    dy_dt = [(r2*i2*m/l2 + r1*i1 - uc) / (m**2/l2 - l1),\
             (r1*i1 + l1*r2*i2/m - uc) / (m - l1*l2/m),\
             i1/c]
    return dy_dt

def main():

    #initialize the vecter of dependent variables
    y0 = [0,0,3000]

    #initialize the other variables
    r1 = 10 ** (-3)
    r2 = 10 ** (-3)
    l1 = 20 * 10 ** (-6)
    l2 = 80 * 10 ** (-6)
    m = 0.9 * (l1 * l2) ** (1/2)
    c = 1000 * 10 ** (-6)    
    t = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 101)

    #build the model
    sol = odeint(cde, y0, t, args=(r1,r2,l1,l2,m,c))

    #plot the figure of solution
    plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0], 'b', label='i1')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

    plt.plot(t, sol[:, 1], 'g', label='i2')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

    plt.plot(t, sol[:, 1], 'r', label='uc')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

main()
```

The I got a completely incorrect results--The solution of the model shows that it doesn't converge
Why do I get a ODEintWarning like that?
How can I get the correct solution?

Comment: Why do you think the model should converge? Is there a Lyapunov function, or does the eigenvalue analysis indicate stability?

Comment: The model comes from a circuit diagram.so It should converge.@LutzL

Comment: Then check for sign errors in the formulas. You might want to check the modelization on a physics or electronics forum of the stackexchange network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing the eigenvalues of this linear system

```
dy1=cde([1,0,0],0,r1,r2,l1,l2,m,c)
dy2=cde([0,1,0],0,r1,r2,l1,l2,m,c)
dy3=cde([0,0,1],0,r1,r2,l1,l2,m,c)

np.linalg.eig([dy1,dy2,dy3])
```

gives the result

```
(array([ -1.63811579e+04,   1.60647105e+04,  -1.24999684e+01]),
 array([[ -6.19266551e-02,  -6.11336770e-02,  -4.10359481e-01],
        [ -4.49479256e-04,   4.48809049e-04,   9.11909417e-01],
        [  9.98080602e-01,  -9.98129487e-01,   5.12941642e-03]]))
```

so that there is a component that grows as `exp(1.606e+04*t)`, which has values `10**n` at times `t=0.00014333*n` which explains the observed rapid growth.

Comment: Thanks.I forgot to solve the ODEs.I only tried to find the numerical solution of it.......It was my fault.

Comment: Computing eigenvalues only provides an alternative numerical solution or a stability analysis of stationary points in the non-linear case. But it does confirm that the `odeint` solution is indeed correct, at least until the float data type is exhausted.